# InstallShield not able to create registry entry in some PC

Tags: installation, windows-installer, installshield

I have Installer for browser plugin for Firefox,chrome and IE.It is working fine in most of the case but in some system when user is trying to install these registry entry is not getting crated.The Installer project is carted using Install Shield 2012.

I have added registry entry Under System Configuration -->Registry

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\MozillaPlugins\@MyPlugin

Any suggestion what is going wrong here.

Comment: Is there a pattern such as 32bit machines work and 64bit machines don't?  If so, do you understand registry reflection on 64bit machines?

Have you logged the installer?  What does it say on the machines that don't seem to work?

Comment: How do you check whether it was created? Try running `C:\Windows\SysWow64\regedit.exe` instead of the default regedit.

Comment: I am getting on both 32 bit and 64 bit